# Spring JPA @GeneratedValue return 0 and error during insertion

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I just started to use Spring Boot and I wanted to try JPARepository.

I created a Model named User which is very basic.

```java
import jakarta.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
public class UserModel {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name = "age")
    private int age;

    public UserModel() {

    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

I use @GeneratedValue to insert the ID. Next, I created a file UserRepository :

```java
@Repository
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<UserModel,Integer> {
}
```

And then a Controller.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;
    
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public String addUser(@RequestBody UserModel user){
        this.userRepository.save(user);
        return "Job's done  |ID :" + user.getId();
    }


}
```

I also added my db connection

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/ostassist
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
```

When I try to POST with a JSON a User, the following line appears : Error 500, Internal Server Error

When I try to print userId, I get 0 or null. I changed the user ID in my db to autoincrement manually and it worked.

What am I doing wrong,

Thanks for your help ! :)

Answer (score 1):

Before persisting the entity, your model just does not have ID. Therefore you get 0 always, even thou the model could be persisted.

```
user = this.userRepository.save(user);
return "Job's done  |ID :" + user.getId();
```

Jpa's `save` method returns the stored entity.

Also, your ID is Long, and your `UserRepository` extends `JpaRepository` with `Integer` as ID. It should be

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository  extends JpaRepository<UserModel,Long> {
}
```

Also, you should open a new transaction when persisting the entity:

```
@PostMapping("/add")
@Transactional
public String addUser(@RequestBody UserModel user){
```